# Dynamically Loading XAML that uses types which have code-behind

Tags: wpf, xaml

Example XAML to be loaded dynamically

```
<Grid xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'     
      xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' 
      xmlns:usercontrols='clr-namespace:App.Views.UserControls'>

         <TextBlock>Why don't you click the button?</TextBlock>

         <usercontrols:SuperButton
         Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenURLNew,RelativeSource=
           {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}"
         CommandParameter="50">

         ClickMe</usercontrols:SuperButton>
</Grid>
```

Loading this fails with 'can not load unknown type usercontrols:superbutton', despite the fact that SuperButton is defined in the same assembly.

I'm guessing this is because SuperButton has associated code-behind? Is there a way to help XamlReader.Load() find what it needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing should work - try using the fully qualified assembly name in `xmlns:usercontrols=''`.

I did this exact thing a while back (perhaps the netGooey library I wrote might be useful for you). netGooey loads XAML dynamically into the page with support for user-defined controls.

My XAML header looked like this:

`<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="499" Height="579"
    xmlns:playback="clr-namespace:inlayShared.ui.controls.playback;assembly=inlayShared"
    xmlns:library="clr-namespace:inlayShared.ui.controls.library;assembly=inlayShared">`

Control use like:

`<playback:volumeSlider Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Margin="42,180,62,0" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" TickFrequency="10" TickPlacement="BottomRight" />`

And the dynamic XAML loading like this:

```
            _gSystem.invokeOnLocalThread((Action)(() =>
            {
                FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(_sUIFile);
                DependencyObject dependencyObject = XamlReader.Load(fileStream) as DependencyObject;
                fileStream.Close();

                if (dependencyObject == null)
                    return;

                Content = dependencyObject;
            }), true);`
```

Perhaps I forgot some key part to getting XAML to notice the custom controls but I'm pretty sure it just ended up working.

Good luck. (Hopefully the fully qualified change fixes it for you)

http://inlay.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/42822#549758

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a bunch. Upvoted and accepting. Will have a look at your netgooey stuff once I get a chance. A paragraph explaining what you have built/trying to achieve would be handy. From what I can see, you have to dig in the code to figure it out at the moment.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not supporting that project anymore so I won't be writing documentation. I mentioned it mainly because there might be some examples of how you should be doing things in there. If you have other WPF/dynamic XAML questions you can reply to this comment with a link to your new question and I'll take a look.